# How to modify Invalid request headers

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to expose an HTTP API to receive data from a device (device will call API), and manipulating the device is not an option.
The problem is that one of the headers in the requests is malformed - specifically it is content-type: multipart/form-data; where a newline is added before the boundary part. this causes header parsing to treat the boundary part as a seperate header which then fails, and the entire requests is failed with this error:

bad request data: "Invalid request header: ' boundary=-----------------110151392918019798021315634022\x0D\x0A'"

So the question is what options there are of manipulating the request before the header parsing fails.

```
[19:38:03 INF] Connection id "0HLPM2MGL7UT1" bad request data: "Invalid request header: ' boundary=-----------------110151392918019798021315634022\x0D\x0A'"
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Invalid request header: ' boundary=-----------------110151392918019798021315634022\x0D\x0A'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.RejectRequestHeader(Byte* headerLine, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseHeaders(TRequestHandler handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& co
nsumed, SequencePosition& examined, Int32& consumedBytes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.IHttpParser<TRequestHandler>.Pa
rseHeaders(TRequestHandler handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined, Int32& consumedBytes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TakeMessageHeaders(ReadOnlySequence`1 buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequenceP
osition& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.ParseRequest(ReadOnlySequence`1 buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePositio
n& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TryParseRequest(ReadResult result, Boolean& endConnection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Comment: None. You have to be able to receive the request before you can manipulate it, and if it's malformed, it will fail at the protocol level. If you just had some application listening on the 80/443 port, which wasn't using HTTP (raw socket), you might be able to do something with that, and have it function like a proxy. However, from the ASP.NET Core side, you're out of luck.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why is manipulating the device out of the question? Maybe you can't personally do it. However, if it's owned hardware, and it's sending malformed HTTP requests, that's a support issue. If it's clients you don't control (as an organization), then you also don't have a responsibility to make them work. They just get rejected until they fix their issues.

Comment: The device is normally communicating with a software component from same manufacturer - for various reasons I need to grab the traffic, so it can go to both this and and some other component as well. Newer versions of the device does not have this problem. I have a working POC in NancyFX, but since we normally use ASP.NET in my company I was hoping to use that here as well.